# Total DNS errors 100% in openshift

Tags: domain-name-system, .htaccess, dns-hosting, openshift-online-2, openshift-origin

From yesterday suddenly my website down and Google webmaster shows Total DNS errors 100%. My app is http://core-ahang2mail.rhcloud.com

I don't know what should I do, Could you please help me?

Finally i rename htaccess (as  @MichaelHampton said) and my problem solved, but now my redirects not working, so could you please help me to solve htaccess problem?

```
# Necessary to prevent problems when using a controller named "index" and having a root index.php
# more here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20918746/1114320
Options -MultiViews

# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# When using the script within a sub-folder, put this path here, like /mysubfolder/
# If your app is in the root of your web folder, then please delete this line or comment it out
# RewriteBase /php-login/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) $1 [NS,NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Remove the 301 redirect that you put in.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I redirect it to https://www.ahang2mail.gq, It's no longer working? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: That's _not_ where it is redirecting to!

Comment: @MichaelHampton So why it working previously?